# VF PDF render : Display related list without gridlines and column title (Professional version so no custom controller)

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf

I am trying to render a PDF with related object list without column titles and grid lines.

I found this apex code for the table :

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Lines List">
    <apex:pageBlockTable align="center" value="{!opportunity.lines__r}" var="line">
    <apex:column value="{!line.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!line.description__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

This is showing the needed info. However it also shows column titles and grid lines, which I don't want to see...
Please note that my VF page is coded in HTML, as I do not have knowledge in Apex...

Thank you much in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to have custom CSS for the related list. Is there a link at the top of your visualforce page to a resource containing the CSS for the page? You'll want to modify that if there is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [apex:dataTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) instead:

```
<apex:dataTable align="center" value="{!opportunity.lines__r}" var="line">
    <apex:column value="{!line.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!line.description__c}"/>
</apex:dataTable>
```

apex:dataTable behaves similarly to apex:pageBlockTable but without styling.

Comment: I prefer this. You can also use `<apex:repeat>` tag if needed to iterate over a collection. Which is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Hope this can help you thinking:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    border: 0px;
}
</style>    
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>{!opportunity.Contact_lookup__r.Name}</td>
    <td>{!opportunity.Contact_lookup__r.Description}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

No borders , No column titles. Change the values in CSS accordingly to get what you want.